# Tag synonym proposal: [dotnetnuke-settings] & [dotnetnuke-module] > [dotnetnuke]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I want to propose and promote that [dotnetnuke-settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnetnuke-settings) and [dotnetnuke-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnetnuke-module) are merged as a synonym of [dotnetnuke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnetnuke). Why? Because [dotnetnuke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnetnuke) tag itself is already a small tag, and there are even less SO users who are able to answer questions about the DNN cms, the modules and core code etc.

So by merging those tags the chances are increased that a knowledgeable user sees the question in the fist place (I have seen question with just the [dotnetnuke-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnetnuke-module) alone by just luck that it was on the homepage of SO)

- [dotnetnuke-settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnetnuke-settings): 383 questions
- [dotnetnuke-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnetnuke-module): 52 questions
- [dotnetnuke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnetnuke): 2748 questions